# In OpenShift HAProxy, how to limit connections per backend/route?

Tags: openshift, haproxy

Problem: Excessive traffic to a single application can reach connection limit for HAProxy and cause a widespread outage in OpenShift cluster.

Solutions considered:

1. Maxconn setting for entire HAProxy. This won't help with isolating applications.
2. Maxconn at the server (pod in OpenShift) level. This is too fine-grained for my purpose.
3. Per client IP limits. There is plenty of examples for this, including a nice OpenShift integration [1], but I don't want to group by client IP, because I don't care about the source of the traffic, only about it's destination.

Destination could be an HAProxy backend (route in OpenShift), or entire application or project, though I have no idea how those OpenShift objects would map to HAProxy configs.

Perhaps someone knowledgeable with HAProxy can steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

[1] https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html#deploy-router-protecting-against-ddos-attacks

Comment: I'm almost sure I remember solving something like this using "stick tables," memory structures that are essentially a key/value store, where the value can be a one of several types, including a counter that increments when requests start and decrements when requests finish... If the counter exceeds a limit based on the "stick" criteria (the key, e.g. the host header), you can start throwing back errors... but I can't remember where I might have done this.

Comment: I've seen many examples using stick-table type ip, enforcing limits on a per client IP basis. I would prefer not to use a key for grouping at all, just populate the table in a single backend scope.